# Parsing Dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have a column in my database that is currently a varchar. the data looks like this:

```
Thu, 4 Jul 2013 09:18:24 
Thu, 11 Jul 2013 10:07:01
Tue, 28 Jan 2014 11:38:37
Fri, 26 Jul 2013 14:13:42
```

I want to be able to convert that to a date so that I can get the most recent record.

Comment: Please describe your most recent effort and the result thereof.

Comment: You will want to use CONVERT() and will need to match your date string to the corresponding date   value.  SQL server is more difficult than Oracle to convert dates.

Comment: @Doug, Mitch Wheat's answer below makes it look pretty easy...

Comment: I am currently stuck on SQL Server 2008, so that is a nice feature in the newer versions.

Comment: Mainstream support for SQL Server 2008 ended on 7/8/2014; Extended support ends on 7/9/2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2012 onwards, you can use [`TRY_PARSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx):

```
-- If the culture argument isn't provided, the language of current session is used.
SELECT TRY_PARSE('Thu, 4 Jul 2013 09:18:24' AS datetime2) AS 'datetime2';
```

> TRY_PARSE: Returns the result of the expression, translated to the requested data
>   type, or **null** if the cast fails.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the string always starts with a three character day literal followed by a comma and space you could for instance use `substring()` to chop off the start and then use `cast()` to convert the string into a proper datetime like so:

```
cast(substring(your_date_col, 6, len(your_date_col)) as datetime)
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2db8e0/1)

There are plenty of other ways to do this; read up on the cast/convert and string functions if you want to know more. (And consider using try_cast/try_convert instead).